# NextAuth with Wildcard / Custom Domains

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, wildcard, next-auth

I have a NextJS application. It's a multi-tenant SaaS application.

The app provides each customer with the option to use a subdomain on our site or to map their custom domain vis CNAME.

I want to allow our customers to allow their employees to login on their subdomain site or custom domain.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
     EMAIL PROVIDER
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: `/login`,
    verifyRequest: `/verify`,
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  callbacks: {

  },
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: 'next-auth.session-token',
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.mysaas.com' : undefined,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false
      }
    },
    callbackUrl: {
      name: 'next-auth.callback-url',
      options: {
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.mysaas.com' : undefined,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false
      }
    },
    csrfToken: {
      name: 'next-auth.csrf-token',
      options: {
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.mysaas.com' : undefined,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false
      }
    }
  }  
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

With the above `[...nextauth]` file, I'm able to make it work with subdomains as I'm using '.mysaas.com' for domain cookie.

However, it doesn't work with a custom domain mapped to a subdomain? How can I achieve that?

If I can set the cookie domain dynamically so that I can dynamically set the domain to the actual domain, then it will work. Like instead of `.mysaas.com`, if I could set it to `.mycustomdomain.com`, if the login page is called from this custom domain, then the problem gets resolved.

However, I cannot find a way to set this cookie domain dynamically. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you completely remove the `domain` options from NextAuth config? Isn't NextAuth using current domain by default?

Comment: @IgorDanchenko This was it. I overcomplicated the solution in my head. If you can post a short answer, I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NextAuth is using current domain by default, completely removing the `domain` prop from your NextAuth config should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I was going over my head :)

Comment: There is one more problem, in the signIn callback, how can I get access to the current domain? I want to know which domain/subdomain the user has signed in from and then apply some logic based on that.

Comment: Can you look at this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544613/nextauth-with-wild-card-custom-domains-signin-logic

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you have to allow login from both subdomain and your custom domain in your configuration. This can be easily done by modifying `cookie` section.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    // EMAIL PROVIDER
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: `/login`,
    verifyRequest: `/verify`,
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  callbacks: {
    session: async (session, user) => {
      // Set the session's domain based on the incoming request
      session.domain = session?.cookies?.nextauth_url
        ? new URL(session.cookies.nextauth_url).hostname
        : undefined;

      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
  },
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: 'next-auth.session-token',
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
      },
    },
    callbackUrl: {
      name: 'next-auth.callback-url',
      options: {
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
      },
    },
    csrfToken: {
      name: 'next-auth.csrf-token',
      options: {
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

If you need help please let me know.

Comment: Can you look at this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544613/nextauth-with-wild-card-custom-domains-signin-logic